# Setting Redux state as a default state when using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a redux action that fetches all data and stores it into a global Redux store.

I want to store that state in a local state using Hooks so that the actual state doesn't get changed when I change it locally.

What I am doing right now is,

```
const [filteredTable, setFilteredTable] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchDatabase();
    props.fetchOptions();
    setFilteredTable(props.filtered_table_data);
}, [])
```

In `useEffect`, the `props.fetchDatabase()` gets the `props.filtered_table_data` and I can see that when I console.log it out.

However, when I use Hooks to store it into a local state and check if it's in there,

`console.log(filteredTable, 'filteredTable')`

just gives me `[]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `props.fetchDatabase()` call is asynchronous, so by the time you are attempting to `setFilteredTable` the `props.filtered_table_data` has not updated yet.

You can try something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchDatabase();
    props.fetchOptions();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredTable(props.filtered_table_data);
}, [props.filtered_table_data]);
```

Note that this effect will run every time `filtered_table_data` changes, so you may need to wrap around the code in the callback with some sort of condition if you want to restrict setting the local state.

Comment: But I need to call `props.fetchData()` when the component gets load

Comment: You can still call `props.fetchDatabase()` in a separate effect that only runs on component load. I've modified my original answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect`'s callback with `[]` as hook's second argument is only being called once when component just mounted. Inside it `fetchDatabase`, and `fetchOptions` callbacks are called, and right after that (when data isn't yet fetched) you call `setFilteredTable`, that's why there are empty  array occurs in `filteredTable`.

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: One possible option is to add another `useEffect` hook which will look on `filtered_table_data` and when it arrives call setFilteredTable:


`useEffect(() => setFilteredTable(filtered_table_data), [filtered_table_data])`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but React-Redux provides some [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks) for accessing the redux store.
The one that might be of interest to you is the `useSelector()` hook.

Here's an example usage:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
  const tableData = useSelector(state => state.tableData);
  ...
}
```